# can't change assets image color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm developing a flutter web, and I checked on the mobile web that the color of the icon image is strange.

```
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage('assets/images/heart_selected.png'),
        color: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
    ),
```

I'm printing the heart icon as below, and the color of the icon should be 'redAccent' as set in the code.
And when I checked on the web, it was printed well. However, when viewed on the mobile web, it is output only in black, not in the set color. (the same goes for other colors.)  Perhaps the color of the icon image has not been changed at all.

There is no problem with the flutter icon widget. May I know the cause of this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Replace **ImageIcon** with **Image.asset**. It's Work for.

```
Image.asset("assets/icons/Location.png",
              height: 16,
              color: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Image.asset instead of image icon. Image. Asset also has a color key available to customise

Answer (score 0):

My original icon is having different color(red).
_selectedIndex is the state variable to track the current selected item index.

```
const PRIMARY = Color(0xFFB9436E);
const INACTIVE_GREY = Color(0xFF888888);
------------------------------------------
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          AssetConstants.homeIcon,
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? PRIMARY : INACTIVE_GREY,
        ),
        label: 'Home',
      )
```